# Apache: Redirect blog.foobar.com to www.foobar.com

Tags: apache, apache2

I have a site at blog.foobar.com that I have closed down, and I want any
page requested there to be forwarded to www.foobar.com

I want my VirtualHost config to do this for me. I currently have the following lines that does nearly what I want but not exactly:

redirect permanent / http://www.foobar.com

Unfortunately what happens is that if I ask for blog.foobar.com instead of forwarding to www.foobar.com it serves the pages on blog.foobar.com instead.

Is there a way doing this in the VirtualHost config or should I use a .htaccess file instead?

Regards

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Redirect` directive in the context of either a VirtualHost or a .htaccess file.  However, what you probably want is a [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch):

```
RedirectMatch permanent (.*)$ http://www.foobar.com$1
```

With that inside your `blog.foobar.com` VirtualHost, any request to `blog.foobar.com` would be directed to the same page on `www.foobar.com`, ie. `blog.foobar.com/my/page` would go to `www.foobar.com/my/page`.